# Value does not change when in parameters

Tags: javascript, parameters

I am having difficulties changing values sent in with parameters to a function, and I have no idea why it doesn't change the value outside of the function. What have I done wrong? =)

```
hero= {health:25}

increasehealth(hero.health);

function increasehealth(hp)
{
hp+=5;

}

alert(hero.health);
```

[Here is the script on jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kkQC4/3/)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can do `hero.health+=5` but `hp` will not refer to `hero.health` inside of `increasehealth`

Comment: You're passing a copy of the value, not a pointer to it.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript parameters are passed by value.

You passed the value 5 to the parameter `hp`

`hp` is a *completely different variable* from the argument `hero.health`.  That's what pass by value means.  The parameter is a new variable.  Draw it as its own separate box.  So in this case, changing `hp` will not affect the argument.

If you would have instead passed `hero` to `hp` and implemented the body of your function as `hp.health += 5` you would have seen what you expected.  This is because `hp` would have been a separate variable, of course, but its value would be a reference to, or pointer to, `hero`.  So `hp.health` would be exactly the same cell as `hero.health` and `hero.health` would be changed.

In pictures:

Your original code:

```
hero  +--+               +----+
         |           hp  | 5  |
         v               +----+
+------------+
|            |
| health 25  |
|            |
+------------+
```

Here changing hp to 10 leaves hero.health untouched.

Now, the other way, where you pass `hero` itself to `hp`:

```
hero  +--+               +----+
         |           hp  | *  |
         v               +-|--+
+------------+             |
|            |             |
| health 25  |<------------+
|            |
+------------+
```

Now if the body of your function said `hp.health += 5` follow the pointer to see what gets changed!

Here is a more general approach that you can use, which should help you with the question you asked in the comments.

You could create a function that takes an object and a property to increase, like so:

```
function increase(object, property, amount) {
    object[property] += amount;
}
```

Here is how you would use it in your hero example:

```
var hero = {health: 25}
increase(hero, 'health', 5)
```

Now `hero.health` is 30.

If you need to use this in a click listener, it would work like this, assuming you had the necessary three values already set somewhere in your script:

```
increaseButton.onclick = function () {increase(obj, prop, amt);}
```

For a particular button you can even write:

```
increaseHeroHealthByFiveButton.onclick = function () {increase(hero, 'health', 5);}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explaining answer =) The problem I have is that I HAVE to have the variable sent in as a parameter, because I have dozens of different variables that I have to be able to run through the same function. I noticed that I can't use hero.health=increasehealth(hero.health) in the html button onclick. Do you have any clue on how to go around this?

Comment: Yes, added to answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
// implicit global mutation 

var hero = {health: 25}

function increasehealth() {
    hero.health += 5;
}    

increasehealth();

alert(hero.health);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z3qXz/)

```
// explicit global mutation 

var hero = {health: 25}

function increasehealth(hp) {
    return hp += 5;
}    

hero.health = increasehealth(hero.health);

alert(hero.health);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qhpx7/)

```
// Object Oriented (this would be my recommendation)

function Hero() {
    this.health = 25;
}

Hero.prototype.increaseHealth = function () {
    this.health += 5;
}    

var hero = new Hero();

hero.increaseHealth();

alert(hero.health);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7VcML/1/)

Comment: Thank you kindly for the answer but this does not really fill in the requirements of my script :/ I NEED to send it in with parameters, instead of having a function for every variable. The second ption you made, is there any way to use it with html buttons? They do not seem to take return; too friendly =)

Comment: You'd have to attach a click handler to a button using [addEventListener](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/element.addEventListener.html) or [onClick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.onclick?redirect=no).